# Hive's RegexSerDe not giving the correct output

Tags: regex, hive

I tried to parse the below input string using Hive RegexSerDe but i am not getting the expected output.  I really don't know whether the problem sits in my regex query or in RegexSerDe. My regex query is working as expected in the other online regex simulator but its not working in hive's RegexSerDe. Could someone please help me to understand what goes wrong here?

i am using apachehive-0.9.0 version.

**Input:**

> 1::Toy Story (1995)::Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy

**My Expected output:**

> 1 Toy Story  1995  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy

**My hive query:**

```
CREATE TABLE myMovie3(  
id STRING,  
name STRING,  
year STRING,  
category STRING)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^(.*?)::(.*)\(([0-9]*)\)::(.*)$","output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s") 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Actual output that i got from the regex is:**

```
hive> select * from mymovie3;  
OK  
1   Toy Story (1995)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is the cause. Although it's perfect in normal context, RegexSerDe is a Java class which needs escaping for the backslashes. Use the following :

```
^(.*?)::(.*)\\(([0-9]*)\\)::(.*)$
```